# How to use update to insert a new value in another table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to triggers in MySQL.
I'm trying to update the column "product_in_stock" from the table "product".
For that i'm using a trigger that after an insert on "orders" table, it will make an subtraction of product_in_stock (from product) with quantity (from orders).

These is my trigger so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    quantityupdate
AFTER INSERT ON orders FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE 
    product
SET 
    product.product_in_stock = product.product_in_stock- orders.quantity
WHERE 
    product.product_id = NEW.product_id;
```

The tables (just an example)

Product

| product_id | product_in_stock |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 10 |

Orders

| orders_id | quantity (bough) |
| --- | --- |
| First | 5 |

Expected outcome:

Product

| product_id | product_in_stock |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 5 |

Comment: instead of orders.quantity write new.quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    quantityupdate
AFTER INSERT ON orders FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE 
    product
SET 
    product.product_in_stock = product.product_in_stock- new.quantity
WHERE 
    product.product_id = NEW.product_id;
```